# error al abrir folder en ionic 5 con un proyecto de ionic 4

Tags: ionic

el año pasado trabaje con ionic 4 pero ahora quiero abrir una app en ionic 5 y me marca algunos errores me podrian ayudar [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios cambios entre la versión 4 y la 5. Por empezar deberías actualizar tu versión de ionic y actualizar las librerías con npm i. En la versión 5 hay cambios en la manera de llamar a las directivas y en el routing (muy importante).